# Detecting partial shapes in an image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, shapes

I am trying to detect shapes in an image where these shapes might be either a bit skewed/deformed or incomplete. A shape consists of a line and an arc (they are markings on a football pitch). Let me give you an example.

Shape to be detected:

[image: shape]

Image to search through:

[image]

I've tried a couple of approaches:

1) using SimpleBlobDetector of OpenCV. This detects a roundy shape that is a penalty area arc, but doesn't fit it exactly. That's some starting point, but I am worried it's not robust enough, because it e.g. didn't detect the other incomplete circle (on the half line).
[image: SimpleBlobDetector]

2) I also tried detecting circles with HoughCircles of OpenCV, but none was detected.

3) I also tried detecting contours on the base image and comparing these with the shape using the matchShapes of OpenCV. This gave a lot of false positives.

4) Finally, I had an idea for a custom implementation that would identify all the vertical lines in an image (with HoughLinesP of OpenCV), and then try to "swipe" the shape image (shown on the first picture of this post) down each line, calculating the % of matching pixels (in this case this would be the pixels that add to 255). I haven't implemented that yet completely, as I see some problems with it: speed and the possible deformations to the sought shapes (as seen even on the examples I pasted).

I`d be grateful for some hints on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Try and see if template matching can work in your case - https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: I read that but never used, as I was under the impression that it will only find the exact match. Was I wrong? Also, how does it deal with rotation, scale, etc.?

Comment: I couldnt understand exactly which parts you wanna detect?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk parts the lines of the football field (as shown on the first exhibit).

Comment: I think you can make template matching work by progressively scaling image. To make it more performant, you can perhaps work with 2x, 4x or even 16x smaller images. Given that you do not lose any details for matching. The same thing you can do with orientation by rotating template. But that would take serious hit on performance. You can also try out feature matching https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html.